# Can an aurora australis be bright enough to illuminate someone's face?

Tags: auroras

If two people are standing next to each other during a polar night, and the brightest possible aurora is occurring overhead, could one person see the other person's face clearly?

Comment: You've added "australis". Apparently, the northern and southern lights don't differ principally but their appearance changes by daytime. Source: https://www.universetoday.com/35058/northern-southern-aurorae-are-siblings-but-not-twins/. @trondhansen 's answer is still valid, it seems only that the one face is illuminated in the morning, the other in the evening ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your eyes are fully adapted to the darkness you will be able to see a persons face in the light from the auroras.

By fully adapted to darkness means sitting in a totally dark room for 20+ minutes before you start looking at the night sky. The time you will need to adapt depends on your age.

Any bright light will destroy your night vision. As we get older our night vision will get poorer so young people will see better at night than older people do.